# IIS reverse proxy using regular proxy

Tags: iis, proxy, reverse-proxy

I use an IIS as reverse proxy. However, the target page can only be reached via a "regular" proxy.

Currently I always get a bad gateway error. My guess is that the rewrite module of the IIS does not consider the proxy settings of the system and therefore does not get a connection to the target page.

Do I have to define own proxy settings for the rewrite module? Or is it even possible to use a reverse proxy behind a normal proxy with the IIS?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to add the proxy setting in the applicatiohost.config file.

This will make all the request to use the proxy to send to another server.

More details, you could refer to below setting:

Related article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings

Applicationhost.config file path:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\
```

Setting example:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
        proxyaddress="http://10.0.2.231:42"
        bypassonlocal="true"
      />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, unfortunately I could not solve my problem with it. I tried the setting in the "applicationHost.config" as well as in the "web.config".

If I call the page with the rewrtie I get an error code "503.2".

Comment: As far as I know, the 503.2 means the "The serverRuntime@appConcurrentRequestLimit setting is being exceeded. " error. That means there are too many request are send to the server. Could you please tell me is there any other url rewrite rule you have used in your IIS server?

Comment: On the server there are indeed several rewriting rules. But it's probably not due to the number of requests, since it's a test system with little to no traffic.
The other rewrites are working, but they also show at locale sites, the rewrite in question points to the internet.